# Alter Tables that are replicated in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2008-r2

We have two databases and some tables in them are replicated.
We want to add to table new rows and also include them in replication.
How can we do this?

Example:
We have `[dbo1].Table1` and `[dbo2].Table2` that are replicated with all columns and have identically structure.
We want to add new column `Column1` to both of the tables and include this column to replication.

Comment: What type of replication? The answers may be different for different types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article ["Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx) should cover most of what you need to know. Unlike older versions of SQL Server, you should just be able to make the DDL changes (assuming you haven't unset the replication defaults).

As the article mentions, you won't be able to use SSMS to make these changes.