# Check SQL Server Replication Defaults

Tags: sql-server, replication, ddl, alter-table, transactional-replication

We have a database *a* that is replicated to a subscriber db *b* (used for SSRS reporting) every night at 2.45 AM.

We need to add a column to one of the replicated tables since it's source file in our iSeries is having a column added that we need to use in our SSRS reporting db.

I understand (from [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398446/alter-tables-that-are-replicated-in-sql-server-2008-r2) from [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever)) that there is a default setting in SQL Server Replication whereby if we use a T-SQL `ALTER TABLE` DDL statement to add the new column to our table BUPF in the PION database, the change will automatically propagate to the subscriber db.

How can I check the *replication of schema changes* setting to ensure that we will have no issues with the replication following making the change?

Or should I just run `ALTER TABLE BUPF ADD Column BUPCAT Char(5) NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new column to a table and include it in an existing publication, you'll need to use ALTER TABLE < Table > ADD < Column > syntax at the publisher. By default the schema change will be propagated to subscribers, publication property **@replicate_ddl** must be set to true.

You can verify if @replicate_ddl is set to true by executing [sp_helppublication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189782.aspx) and inspecting the @replicate_ddl value.  Likewise, you can set @replicate_ddl to true by using [sp_changepublication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188413.aspx).

See [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx) for more information.

Comment: we found that we need to disable replication on the published table as otherwise we get a replication error message about `sqltrans` or something

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error and you shouldn't need to disable replication to make a schema change.  What is the exact error you are receiving and what syntax are you using to make the schema change?

Comment: I think it was something about `sp_MStran_altertable` and we are using `ALTERTABLE BUPF ADD BUPCAT Char (5) NULL` ...